# Generate constants for database table names and fields?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Is there some way to autogenerate constants for table names and fields? Similar to what T4MVC does for files and folders.

I have some sp's that takes field names and it would be nice to be able to autogen the string constants.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you mean?  You want to have a stored procedure that creates tables based on some sort of template?

Comment: Which language are you planning to use for generating your constants: c# ot t-sql?

Comment: @mishau It doesn't matter if it's c# or t-sql. It should however generate valid c# classes containing constants.

Comment: @adamleerich It could be a stored procedure or a program or anything. It should enumerate the tables and field names and generate valid c# classes with constants containing the table name and the field names.

Comment: @Carl R you really shouldn't have to do this. With the exception of one or two very rare exceptions - such as an app that needs to work with a database metadata that is not known at compile time - the only reason your client app would need a table name is if you're embedding SQL directly in your C# code, which is a big no-no.

Comment: For data-centric apps, even if there is 100% sp's, there can be times when it's very useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) one of the better code generation tools that is often used in conjunction with C# / SQL Server DBs.

It allows you to generate code by loading up schemas (a SQL database, or a hand-crafted XML file), and using these as input to various templates.  CodeSmith itself comes with some fairly good templates for a variety of things, such as creating full CRUD stored procedures for all tables you specify, or entire data access layers in C# (NetTiers, CSLA, etc).  It's relatively easy to create your own template for pretty much anything you can think of, and I have seen implementations where enums were generated from actual values in tables, or the tables themselves.

The only issue is that CodeSmith is not free, but it's definitely worthwhile to look at.

Comment: I would look at t4 templates if you want a free solution. You can also do this fairly easily depending on your level using codedom. If you have a more complex code to generate you should use a third-party solution such as codesmith.